# Flutter/Dart Non-Nullable - Use Snapshot data directly

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am using expansion tiles in my code, and was using snapshot.data.length then accessing data directly from the snapshot when I was using the nullable version of Dart.

However, I changed it down the line to the non-nullable version, and it is throwing the errors below -- **how can I access the snapshot data, or convert it into a List/Map to be able to use it**?
[The attached image shows the errors it's showing me. I tried converting the snapshot.data to another var but that didn't work either.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S4PU.png)

Comment: 1. where is "items" in "items.length" coming from? Don't see it defined anywhere
2. what does "helper.getAllBudgetItemsByDate..." return?
3. you can't access snapshot.data before there is any data. So you have to check "snapshot.hasData" before calling it
4. what error is displayed if you hover on "itemCount: snapshot.data.length? I guess you have to use "snapshot.data!.length" here.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question!
1. That's my mistake - it's meant to read itemsAll.length
2. It returns List<BudgetItem>
3. The snapshot has data -- if I put a print statement above the if statement to print out snapshot.data, It shows data in the snapshot.
4. The error is "The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (This error is the same one I'm getting when I try snapshot.data!.length). If I take out the !, the error is "The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.

Comment: Can you try "(snapshot.data as List<BudgetItem>).length"? This looks like a casting error. The snapshot.data is not recognized as a List of "BudgetItem" and therefore you cant access properties like length. If this doesnt fix it, lets setup a dart pad with all the code from your Widget holding this FutureBuilder

Answer (score 0):

So I hope this solves your problem. Attached the code and some comments. I tested it in Dartpad and it worked fine like that. If it's still not working please provide more code.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // you need to define what the future builder will return
    return FutureBuilder<List<BudgetItem>>(
      // helper.getAllItems() needs to have a return type 
      // "Future<List<BudgetItem>>"
      future: helper.getAllItems(), 
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              // snapshot.data[index] is now from type "BudgetItem" and you can
              // access whatever properties it has
              return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data![index].title));
            },
          );
        }

        // if there is no data you still need to return sth like a loading spinner
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
```